# Why is this selector taking priority over a more specific selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

According to what I previously thought, elements are lower in specificity than classes, and of course nested classes. Why then, does this `<P>` tag take priority? It's physically closer to the text, true, but I would think the more specific selector would be `.a .b` override it.

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <p>asdf</p> <!-- this text is 15pt red -->
  </div>
</div>

p{
  color: red;
}
.a .b{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/vekojituta/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: `.a .b` is setting style for `div` and not the `p` whereas the `p` selector is setting style directly for `p`. So, specificity plays no part here. Specificity is applied only when two or more rules apply to the same element.

Comment: @Harry I think this should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Error404: I agree but I think this is a duplicate (though not word for word) because I've seen similar questions in the past. Just too lazy to search for it :P

Comment: @Harry Yes, I also think that it is a duplicate (it sounds very familiar) but I do not know the words to search it. Anyway, I think your comment is more clarify than the current answers.

Answer (score 1):

The more specific selector doesn't match the element at all.

`p { color: red; }` overrides the default of `color: inherit`.

Answer (score 1):

The more specific selector would be:

```
.a .b p{color: blue; font-size: 15pt;}
```

That way it will only target "p" under "b" that is under "a" and no other "p" (very specific).

[This article has help me understand the selectors a little more.](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)